# Giving Optimizer Hint on DDL Queries

Tags: mysql, locking, alter-table, query-hints, optimizer-hints

How to give optimizer hints on DDL query ?

I have a use case to set lock_wait_timeout in an alter query. I do prefer to give it for that statement alone. Is it possible to give optimizer hint in the same statement itself?

PS : I do not prefer setting lock_wait_timeout for that entire session.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _"for that entire session"_. Just set it before you run your alter query and then revert it afterwards.

Comment: Which DDL query?

Comment: I need to do it for Alter Query (add column/ delete column/ modify column). @RickJames.

Comment: @nnichols I am looking for a way to set in the statement itself, instead of running before and after the alter query.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do it within your ALTER statement. Why would you want to?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  There have been significant changes in recent versions.  Some of the changes depend on the specifics of the column changes; so we need more details.  If necessary, obfuscate the names and leave out other columns.  But do not leave out datatypes, nor the Primary key nor other indexes.